# New environment for questions and answers

Tags: environments, exam, newtheorem

I want to create my own environment with an "answer" parameter and optional "font style" parameter.

From the new environment, with name QandA for example, I need the following functionality.

```
\begin{QandA}[\itshape]{24} 

...Your question here...

\end{QandA}
```

Execution of the following code should lead to the output of the text of the task after the spelling of the word "problem" in `\it` style and printing the answer "24" after the spelling of the word "answer". Namely:

*Problem 1:*

...Your question here...

**Answer 1:**

24

I could handle this task with particular ease only if I could pass environment parameters to `{enddef}` brackets in environment definition.

How can I handle this challenge? Maybe the `exam` package can help me somehow?

Comment: Just a general comment: you may want `\itshape` rather than `\it`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problems are that you want to compress two environments into one, and besides that you cannot use stuff like `#1` in the second argument of `\newenvironment`. The second one is solved by storing it into a command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{QandA}% Create new counter.
\newenvironment{QandA}[2][]{%
   \refstepcounter{QandA}% Step environment counter.
   \newcommand{\myArg}[0]{#2}% Store answer-argument.
   \medskip% Put a little vertical space.
   \newline\noindent {#1 Problem~\theQandA.}%
   \newline\noindent%
}{%
   \medskip%
   \newline\noindent\textbf{Answer~\theQandA.}%
   \newline\noindent%
   \myArg% Here we use the stored argument.
   \medskip\newline%
}


\begin{document}
   
   \noindent Some text.
   \begin{QandA}[\itshape]{First answer.}
      Your first question here.
   \end{QandA}
   Some text.
   \begin{QandA}[\scshape\bfseries]{Second answer.}
      Your second question here.
   \end{QandA}
   Some text.
   \begin{QandA}{Third answer.}
      No optional argument.
   \end{QandA}
   Some text.
   
\end{document}
```

[image]